# Django - Inline formset - storing only the last row of the child model (in 1 to many relationship)

Tags: python, django

Python :3.6.2  Django : 1.11.4

We are trying to use foreignkey across apps.  Address is consumed by both customer and agent.  We are also using inline formset.  Form showing up correct. Please see below for the picture.

[Create Agent Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQtTv.jpg)

However, when you save it, it saves just the just last of address.  Also please note that in edit, a blank line is added which I think should not added by default. Please see below for the pic.

[Edit Agent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26T4Y.jpg)

Folder structure

> apps (Folder) 
>      agent (app) 
>           models.py 
>           views.py

customer (app) 
            models.py 
          views.py 
      sharedmodels(app) 
            models.py 
           forms.py

agent/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.db import transaction
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView

from apps.agent.models import Agent
from apps.sharedmodels.forms import AgentAddressFormSet
from multiApps.logger import log


class AgentList(ListView):
    model = Agent


class AgentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Agent
    fields = ['first_name']
    #log.info(fields)

class AgentAddrLocArefCreate(CreateView):
    model = Agent
    fields = ['first_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('agent-list')



    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(AgentAddrLocArefCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    log.info('i m here 1')
    if self.request.POST:
        log.info('i m here 2')

        #data['location'] = LocationFormSet(self.request.POST)

        data['address'] = AgentAddressFormSet(self.request.POST)

        #data['agentreferal'] = AgentReferalFormSet(self.request.POST)

    else:

        #data['location'] = LocationFormSet()

        data['address'] = AgentAddressFormSet()

        #data['agentreferal'] = AgentReferalFormSet()

    return data



    def form_valid(self, form):

    context = self.get_context_data()

    #location = context['location']

    agentaddress = context['address']
    log.info('i m here 3')

    #agentreferal = context['agentreferal']

    with transaction.atomic():

        self.object = form.save()



        #if location.is_valid() and address.is_valid() and agentreferal.is_valid():
        if agentaddress.is_valid():
        #location.instance = self.object

        agentaddress.instance = self.object

        #agentreferal.instance = self.object

        #location.save()

        agentaddress.save()

        #agentreferal.save()

    return super(AgentAddrLocArefCreate, self).form_valid(form)



class AgentAddrLocArefUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Agent
    fields = ['first_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('agent-list')
    # log.info('i m here 4')



    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    data = super(AgentAddrLocArefUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    log.info(data)
    if self.request.POST:
        log.info('i m here 5')

        #data['location'] = LocationFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

        data['address'] = AgentAddressFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

        #data['agentreferal'] = AgentReferalFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

    else:

        #data['location'] = LocationFormSet(instance=self.object)

        data['address'] = AgentAddressFormSet(instance=self.object)

        #data['agentreferal'] = AgentReferalFormSet(instance=self.object)

    return data



    def form_valid(self, form):

    context = self.get_context_data()

    #location = context['location']

    agentaddress = context['address']
    log.info('i m here 6')

    #agentreferal = context['agentreferal']

    with transaction.atomic():

        self.object = form.save()



        #if location.is_valid() and \
        if agentaddress.is_valid():
        #location.instance = self.object

        agentaddress.instance = self.object

        #agentreferal.instance = self.object

        #location.save()

        agentaddress.save()

        #agentreferal.save()



    return super(AgentAddrLocArefUpdate, self).form_valid(form)


def brokenview(request):
    # first, intentionally log something
    log.info('This is a manually logged INFO string.')
    log.debug('This is a manually logged DEBUG string.')
    # then have the view raise an exception (e.g. something went wrong)
    raise Exception('This is an exception raised in a view.')
    # return HttpResponse('hello')
```

sharedmodels/forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, inlineformset_factory

from apps.agent.models import Agent
from apps.customer.models import Customer
from .models import *


class AgentAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Address
    exclude = ('customer',)

class AddressForm1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Address
    exclude = ('agent',)

AgentAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Agent, Address, form=AgentAddressForm, extra=1)
AddressFormSet1 = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Address, form=AddressForm1, extra=1)
#LocationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Agent, Location, form=LocationForm, extra=1)
```

***One other point: We are successful in doing this within one app. 
Any immediate help on this really appreciated.